# Безопасен ли вызов базового конструктора при инициализации дочернего объекта?

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

Есть класс А :

```
class A {
 public:
  A(int value) : value_{value} {};
 private:
  int value_;
}
```

И класс B наследник от класса А:

```
class B : public A{
  В() : А(100) {};
};
```

**Вопрос:**
Безопасен ли подобный конструктор у В класса? Не приведет ли он к неопеределенному поведению на каких либо системах?

Comment: Приведет к некомпилируемости — надо `A(int value) : value_{value} {};` :) Других проблем нет. Кстати, в вашем варианте не вызвать конструктор `A` с каким-то конкретным значением вы просто не сможете...

Comment: Да, забыл поставить фигурные скобочки. Поправил в примере. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: А почему вы сомневаетесь? Язык это разрешает. Я конечно понимаю, что в C++ куда ни плюнь везде UB, но тут ему неоткуда взяться.

Comment: А конструктор базового класса в любом случае вызывается при инициализации объекта дочернего класса. Если не написать `А(100)`, то компилятор автоматически добавит вызов конструктора по-умолчанию. Еще нет необходимости в `;` после закрывающий фигурной скобки метода.